# Unreal Engine Pakaging Error: LogPackageName: Warning: DoesPackageExist called on PackageName that will always return false. Reason: Input''was empty

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

So I have created a game in Unreal engine 5.2 and want to package it but it gives the error :
" LogPackageName: Warning: DoesPackageExist called on PackageName that will always return false. Reason: Input '' was empty. "
Does anyone have a solution for it?

I tried deleting derived data save, saved, and intermediate but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

found this @unrealengine.com forum

So I cracked out on the engine code and was able to track down the actual cause of the error. It ended up being a caching system error trying to point to a reference from the old engine cache that was now invalid. I was able to fully fix the issue by clearing/deleting the project build/temp data not only in the project folder, but also in the AppData/Local folder. After that I rebuilt the project files and the error does not happen anymore in any system. If after doing any of this you get crashes just validate the assets in the Asset Actions menu and they will stop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).